# Basic encrypting of a text file

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, jet

I am trying to encrypt a file.  I don't need fancy encrypting, just need to keep wandering eyes off of it.  I found a function called szEncryptDecrypt online (https://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5676) that would be perfect for what I need, as it is simple to use, and obscures the data.  However, I can't seem to get it working when reading from a file. Passing a string to it in a macro and decrypting it again works fine, but writing to a file then reading it does not work.

I have a write sub, a read sub and the encryption sub. The read a write sub appear to work correctly if non encrypted data is used (unless there are hidden characters it is getting also).

I tried the trim function on the string before decrypting it, but that did not work.

```
Option Compare Database

Sub WriteSettingsFile()
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim fld As DAO.Field
  Set db = CurrentDb
  
  'Open Setings File name
  Dim filePath As String
  Dim TextFile As Integer
  
  TextFile = FreeFile
  filePath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\settings.cfg"
  Open filePath For Output As TextFile
  
  Print #TextFile, szEncryptDecrypt("Hello World")
  
  Close TextFile
End Sub


Sub ReadSettingsFile()
  Dim strFilename As String
  strFilename = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\settings.cfg"
  Dim strTextLine As String
  Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
  Open strFilename For Input As #iFile
  
  Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strTextLine
    MsgBox strTextLine                    'Not Encrypted
    MsgBox szEncryptDecrypt(strTextLine)  'Encrypted
  Loop
  
Close #iFile
End Sub


Function szEncryptDecrypt(ByVal szData As String) As String
  ' This key value can be changed to alter the encryption,
  ' but it must be the same for both encryption and decryption.
  Const KEY_TEXT As String = "asdfghjkl"
  ' The KEY_OFFSET is optional, and may be any value 0-64.
  ' Likewise, it needs to be the same coming/going.
  Const KEY_OFFSET As Long = 0

  Dim bytKey() As Byte
  Dim bytData() As Byte
  Dim lNum As Long
  Dim szKey As String

  For lNum = 1 To ((Len(szData) \ Len(KEY_TEXT)) + 1)
    szKey = szKey & KEY_TEXT
  Next lNum

  bytKey = Left$(szKey, Len(szData))
  bytData = szData

  For lNum = LBound(bytData) To UBound(bytData)
    If lNum Mod 2 Then
      bytData(lNum) = bytData(lNum) Xor (bytKey(lNum) + KEY_OFFSET)
    Else
      bytData(lNum) = bytData(lNum) Xor (bytKey(lNum) - KEY_OFFSET)
    End If
  Next lNum

  szEncryptDecrypt = bytData
End Function


Sub TestEncrypt()
'This sub works fine
 Dim str As String
 str = szEncryptDecrypt("Hello World!")
 MsgBox "Encrypted" & vbNewLine & str
 MsgBox "Decrypted" & vbNewLine & szEncryptDecrypt(str)
End Sub
```

Is there a better encryption function for use with text files?

Comment: I also modified the KEY_TEXT and KEY_OFFSET values.  KEY_TEXT doesn't seem to affect it.  When KEY_OFFSET is 0, it decrypts most of the text, but cuts off the last few characters.  A value of 1 returns text characters, but they are not correct.  Any other character returns only question marks '???????'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would certainly recommend Erik's route but, to answer your question directly, your trouble is, that you generate binary data with non-ascii characters.

That, however, can be solved by using **Base64** encoding/decoding like this:

```vb
Sub WriteSettingsFile()
    
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    'Open Setings File name
    Dim FilePath  As String
    Dim TextFile  As Integer
    
    TextFile = FreeFile
    FilePath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\settings.cfg"
    
    Open FilePath For Output As #TextFile
    Print #TextFile, Encode64(szEncryptDecrypt("Hello World"))
    Close #TextFile
  
End Sub


Sub ReadSettingsFile()
    
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim strTextLine As String
    Dim TextFile    As Integer
    
    TextFile = FreeFile
    strFilename = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\settings.cfg"
    
    Open strFilename For Input As #TextFile
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, strTextLine
        MsgBox strTextLine                              ' Not decrypted
        MsgBox szEncryptDecrypt(Decode64(strTextLine))  ' Decrypted
    Loop
    Close #TextFile
    
End Sub
```

This requires two supporting functions, and then your code starts to pile up a bit:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const clOneMask = 16515072          '000000 111111 111111 111111
Private Const clTwoMask = 258048            '111111 000000 111111 111111
Private Const clThreeMask = 4032            '111111 111111 000000 111111
Private Const clFourMask = 63               '111111 111111 111111 000000

Private Const clHighMask = 16711680         '11111111 00000000 00000000
Private Const clMidMask = 65280             '00000000 11111111 00000000
Private Const clLowMask = 255               '00000000 00000000 11111111

Private Const cl2Exp18 = 262144             '2 to the 18th power
Private Const cl2Exp12 = 4096               '2 to the 12th
Private Const cl2Exp6 = 64                  '2 to the 6th
Private Const cl2Exp8 = 256                 '2 to the 8th
Private Const cl2Exp16 = 65536              '2 to the 16th

Public Function Encode64(ByVal sString As String) As String

    Dim bTrans(63) As Byte, lPowers8(255) As Long, lPowers16(255) As Long, bOut() As Byte, bIn() As Byte
    Dim lChar As Long, lTrip As Long, iPad As Integer, lLen As Long, lTemp As Long, lPos As Long, lOutSize As Long
    
    For lTemp = 0 To 63                                 'Fill the translation table.
        Select Case lTemp
            Case 0 To 25
                bTrans(lTemp) = 65 + lTemp              'A - Z
            Case 26 To 51
                bTrans(lTemp) = 71 + lTemp              'a - z
            Case 52 To 61
                bTrans(lTemp) = lTemp - 4               '1 - 0
            Case 62
                bTrans(lTemp) = 43                      'Chr(43) = "+"
            Case 63
                bTrans(lTemp) = 47                      'Chr(47) = "/"
        End Select
    Next lTemp

    For lTemp = 0 To 255                                'Fill the 2^8 and 2^16 lookup tables.
        lPowers8(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp8
        lPowers16(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp16
    Next lTemp

    iPad = Len(sString) Mod 3                           'See if the length is divisible by 3
    If iPad Then                                        'If not, figure out the end pad and resize the input.
        iPad = 3 - iPad
        sString = sString & String(iPad, Chr(0))
    End If

    bIn = StrConv(sString, vbFromUnicode)               'Load the input string.
    lLen = ((UBound(bIn) + 1) \ 3) * 4                  'Length of resulting string.
    lTemp = lLen \ 72                                   'Added space for vbCrLfs.
    lOutSize = ((lTemp * 2) + lLen) - 1                 'Calculate the size of the output buffer.
    ReDim bOut(lOutSize)                                'Make the output buffer.
    
    lLen = 0                                            'Reusing this one, so reset it.
    
    For lChar = LBound(bIn) To UBound(bIn) Step 3
        lTrip = lPowers16(bIn(lChar)) + lPowers8(bIn(lChar + 1)) + bIn(lChar + 2)    'Combine the 3 bytes
        lTemp = lTrip And clOneMask                     'Mask for the first 6 bits
        bOut(lPos) = bTrans(lTemp \ cl2Exp18)           'Shift it down to the low 6 bits and get the value
        lTemp = lTrip And clTwoMask                     'Mask for the second set.
        bOut(lPos + 1) = bTrans(lTemp \ cl2Exp12)       'Shift it down and translate.
        lTemp = lTrip And clThreeMask                   'Mask for the third set.
        bOut(lPos + 2) = bTrans(lTemp \ cl2Exp6)        'Shift it down and translate.
        bOut(lPos + 3) = bTrans(lTrip And clFourMask)   'Mask for the low set.
        If lLen = 68 Then                               'Ready for a newline
            bOut(lPos + 4) = 13                         'Chr(13) = vbCr
            bOut(lPos + 5) = 10                         'Chr(10) = vbLf
            lLen = 0                                    'Reset the counter
            lPos = lPos + 6
        Else
            lLen = lLen + 4
            lPos = lPos + 4
        End If
    Next lChar
    
    If bOut(lOutSize) = 10 Then lOutSize = lOutSize - 2 'Shift the padding chars down if it ends with CrLf.
    
    If iPad = 1 Then                                    'Add the padding chars if any.
        bOut(lOutSize) = 61                             'Chr(61) = "="
    ElseIf iPad = 2 Then
        bOut(lOutSize) = 61
        bOut(lOutSize - 1) = 61
    End If
    
    Encode64 = StrConv(bOut, vbUnicode)                 'Convert back to a string and return it.
    
End Function

Public Function Decode64(ByVal sString As String) As String

    Dim bOut() As Byte, bIn() As Byte, bTrans(255) As Byte, lPowers6(63) As Long, lPowers12(63) As Long
    Dim lPowers18(63) As Long, lQuad As Long, iPad As Integer, lChar As Long, lPos As Long, sOut As String
    Dim lTemp As Long

    sString = Replace(sString, vbCr, vbNullString)      'Get rid of the vbCrLfs.  These could be in...
    sString = Replace(sString, vbLf, vbNullString)      'either order.

    lTemp = Len(sString) Mod 4                          'Test for valid input.
    If lTemp Then
        Call Err.Raise(vbObjectError, "MyDecode", "Input string is not valid Base64.")
    End If
    
    If InStrRev(sString, "==") Then                     'InStrRev is faster when you know it's at the end.
        iPad = 2                                        'Note:  These translate to 0, so you can leave them...
    ElseIf InStrRev(sString, "=") Then                  'in the string and just resize the output.
        iPad = 1
    End If
     
    For lTemp = 0 To 255                                'Fill the translation table.
        Select Case lTemp
            Case 65 To 90
                bTrans(lTemp) = lTemp - 65              'A - Z
            Case 97 To 122
                bTrans(lTemp) = lTemp - 71              'a - z
            Case 48 To 57
                bTrans(lTemp) = lTemp + 4               '1 - 0
            Case 43
                bTrans(lTemp) = 62                      'Chr(43) = "+"
            Case 47
                bTrans(lTemp) = 63                      'Chr(47) = "/"
        End Select
    Next lTemp

    For lTemp = 0 To 63                                 'Fill the 2^6, 2^12, and 2^18 lookup tables.
        lPowers6(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp6
        lPowers12(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp12
        lPowers18(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp18
    Next lTemp

    bIn = StrConv(sString, vbFromUnicode)               'Load the input byte array.
    ReDim bOut((((UBound(bIn) + 1) \ 4) * 3) - 1)       'Prepare the output buffer.
    
    For lChar = 0 To UBound(bIn) Step 4
        lQuad = lPowers18(bTrans(bIn(lChar))) + lPowers12(bTrans(bIn(lChar + 1))) + _
                lPowers6(bTrans(bIn(lChar + 2))) + bTrans(bIn(lChar + 3))           'Rebuild the bits.
        lTemp = lQuad And clHighMask                    'Mask for the first byte
        bOut(lPos) = lTemp \ cl2Exp16                   'Shift it down
        lTemp = lQuad And clMidMask                     'Mask for the second byte
        bOut(lPos + 1) = lTemp \ cl2Exp8                'Shift it down
        bOut(lPos + 2) = lQuad And clLowMask            'Mask for the third byte
        lPos = lPos + 3
    Next lChar

    sOut = StrConv(bOut, vbUnicode)                     'Convert back to a string.
    If iPad Then sOut = Left$(sOut, Len(sOut) - iPad)   'Chop off any extra bytes.
    Decode64 = sOut

End Function
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting, my code comes with a native VBA Base64 encoder and decoder too, but you seem to have taken a different (slightly lengthier but probably faster) approach.

Comment: @ErikA: Oh, missed that. I haven't used this for years, just recalled I had the module and that it would solve the issue. Ran a test: For small strings like here (i.e passwords), yours is twice as fast; for longer text, yours seems to be slower as the text length increases.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that encryption function you've found is very simple, but very poor. It does simple XORing with an offset. That means if someone can get you to encrypt a known string and can read the output, they can calculate the key. Also, there's no chaining, so we have no [diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion), repeating patterns in the text will lead to the same output, thus common patterns can be inferred.

I've worked on a complicated approach to encryption myself, using AES-128 in CBC mode. However, the code required is fairly long. It uses the [CNG API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-portal) to do the encryption. Others use .Net, which in turn uses CNG, but can result in shorter code. I prefer not to, since that relies on COM objects and those can be overridden.

Let's start with usage: it's simple. Use `EncryptString(StringToEncrypt, Key)` to encrypt a string, and `DecryptString(StringToDecrypt, Key)` to decrypt it again. It uses Base64 encoding to represent the encrypted string, so output should be safe to store in fields that only accept valid unicode strings (also in contrast to the implementation you found).

Then, the fundamentals. AES-128 in CBC mode is a block cipher, so it requires a fixed length key, and also encrypts in full blocks of 128 bits. To work around this, we use SHA1 to reduce our key to a fixed length, and store the length of the input data inside the encrypted string to ignore any padding (additional characters at the end).

Then, in CBC mode, it also requires an initialization vector (IV). We randomly generate that one, and store it without encryption (since we need it to decrypt) at the end of the string. Since we generate the IV randomly, encrypting the same string two times with the same key will result in entirely different encrypted strings, which is often desirable (if you encrypt a password, you don't want someone to be able to check who all have the same password as you).

This code also hashes the data, and stores the encrypted hash with the data. This means it can easily check if your key was valid, and it will not return anything if it was not.

The resulting code is fairly lengthy. It could be reduced by not doing the Base64 encoding in VBA, not using a cryptographically secure random number generator, or using .Net for everything, but that's not desirable imo. I recommend pasting it in a separate module.

```vb
Option Compare Binary
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByRef phAlgorithm As LongPtr, ByVal pszAlgId As LongPtr, ByVal pszImplementation As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hAlgorithm As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptGetProperty Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr, ByVal pszProperty As LongPtr, ByRef pbOutput As Any, ByVal cbOutput As Long, ByRef pcbResult As Long, ByVal dfFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptSetProperty Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr, ByVal pszProperty As LongPtr, ByRef pbInput As Any, ByVal cbInput As Long, ByVal dfFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptCreateHash Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hAlgorithm As LongPtr, ByRef phHash As LongPtr, pbHashObject As Any, ByVal cbHashObject As Long, ByVal pbSecret As LongPtr, ByVal cbSecret As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptHashData Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hHash As LongPtr, pbInput As Any, ByVal cbInput As Long, Optional ByVal dwFlags As Long = 0) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptFinishHash Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hHash As LongPtr, pbOutput As Any, ByVal cbOutput As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptDestroyHash Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hHash As LongPtr) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptGenRandom Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hAlgorithm As LongPtr, pbBuffer As Any, ByVal cbBuffer As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hAlgorithm As LongPtr, ByRef hKey As LongPtr, pbKeyObject As Any, ByVal cbKeyObject As Long, pbSecret As Any, ByVal cbSecret As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptEncrypt Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, pbInput As Any, ByVal cbInput As Long, pPaddingInfo As Any, pbIV As Any, ByVal cbIV As Long, pbOutput As Any, ByVal cbOutput As Long, ByRef pcbResult As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptDecrypt Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, pbInput As Any, ByVal cbInput As Long, pPaddingInfo As Any, pbIV As Any, ByVal cbIV As Long, pbOutput As Any, ByVal cbOutput As Long, ByRef pcbResult As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BCryptDestroyKey Lib "BCrypt.dll" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub RtlMoveMemory Lib "Kernel32.dll" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)

Const BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING  As Long = &H1

Public Type QuadSextet
    s1 As Byte
    s2 As Byte
    s3 As Byte
    s4 As Byte
End Type

Public Function ToBase64(b() As Byte) As String
    Const Base64Table = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
    Dim l As Long
    Dim output As String
    Dim UBoundOut As Long
    UBoundOut = UBound(b) + 1
    If UBoundOut Mod 3 <> 0 Then
        UBoundOut = UBoundOut + (3 - UBoundOut Mod 3)
    End If
    UBoundOut = (UBoundOut \ 3) * 4
    output = String(UBoundOut, vbNullChar)
    Dim qs As QuadSextet
    For l = 0 To (UBound(b) - 2) \ 3
        qs = BytesToQuadSextet(b(l * 3), b(l * 3 + 1), b(l * 3 + 2))
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 1, 1) = Mid(Base64Table, qs.s1 + 1, 1)
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 2, 1) = Mid(Base64Table, qs.s2 + 1, 1)
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 3, 1) = Mid(Base64Table, qs.s3 + 1, 1)
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 4, 1) = Mid(Base64Table, qs.s4 + 1, 1)
    Next
    If UBound(b) + 1 - (l * 3) = 2 Then
        qs = BytesToQuadSextet(b(l * 3), b(l * 3 + 1))
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 1, 1) = Mid(Base64Table, qs.s1 + 1, 1)
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 2, 1) = Mid(Base64Table, qs.s2 + 1, 1)
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 3, 1) = Mid(Base64Table, qs.s3 + 1, 1)
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 4, 1) = "="
    ElseIf UBound(b) + 1 - (l * 3) = 1 Then
        qs = BytesToQuadSextet(b(l * 3))
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 1, 1) = Mid(Base64Table, qs.s1 + 1, 1)
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 2, 1) = Mid(Base64Table, qs.s2 + 1, 1)
        Mid(output, (l * 4) + 3, 2) = "=="
    End If
    ToBase64 = output
End Function

Public Function Base64ToBytes(strBase64 As String) As Byte()
    Dim outBytes() As Byte
    Dim lenBytes As Long
    lenBytes = Len(strBase64) * 3 \ 4
    If Right(strBase64, 1) = "=" Then lenBytes = lenBytes - 1
    If Right(strBase64, 2) = "==" Then lenBytes = lenBytes - 1
    ReDim outBytes(0 To lenBytes - 1)
    Dim l As Long
    Dim qs As QuadSextet
    For l = 0 To lenBytes - 1
        Select Case l Mod 3
            Case 0
                qs = Base64ToQuadSextet(Mid(strBase64, (l \ 3) * 4 + 1, 4))
                outBytes(l) = qs.s1 * 2 ^ 2 + (qs.s2 \ 2 ^ 4)
            Case 1
                outBytes(l) = (qs.s2 * 2 ^ 4 And 255) + qs.s3 \ 2 ^ 2
            Case 2
                outBytes(l) = (qs.s3 * 2 ^ 6 And 255) + qs.s4
        End Select
    Next
    Base64ToBytes = outBytes
End Function

Public Function BytesToQuadSextet(b1 As Byte, Optional b2 As Byte, Optional b3 As Byte) As QuadSextet
    BytesToQuadSextet.s1 = b1 \ 4
    BytesToQuadSextet.s2 = (((b1 * 2 ^ 6) And 255) \ 4) + b2 \ (2 ^ 4)
    BytesToQuadSextet.s3 = (((b2 * 2 ^ 4) And 255) \ 4) + b3 \ (2 ^ 6)
    BytesToQuadSextet.s4 = (((b3 * 2 ^ 2) And 255) \ 4)
End Function

Public Function Base64ToQuadSextet(strBase64 As String) As QuadSextet
    Const Base64Table = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="
    Base64ToQuadSextet.s1 = InStr(Base64Table, Mid(strBase64, 1, 1)) - 1
    Base64ToQuadSextet.s2 = InStr(Base64Table, Mid(strBase64, 2, 1)) - 1
    Base64ToQuadSextet.s3 = InStr(Base64Table, Mid(strBase64, 3, 1)) - 1
    Base64ToQuadSextet.s4 = InStr(Base64Table, Mid(strBase64, 4, 1)) - 1
End Function

Public Function StringToBase64(str As String) As String
    StringToBase64 = ToBase64(StrConv(str, vbFromUnicode))
End Function

Public Function HashBytes(Data() As Byte, Optional HashingAlgorithm As String = "SHA1") As Byte()
    HashBytes = NGHash(VarPtr(Data(LBound(Data))), UBound(Data) - LBound(Data) + 1, HashingAlgorithm)
End Function

Public Function NGHash(pData As LongPtr, lenData As Long, Optional HashingAlgorithm As String = "SHA1") As Byte()
    'Erik A, 2019
    'Hash data by using the Next Generation Cryptography API
    'Loosely based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCNG/creating-a-hash-with-cng
    'Allowed algorithms:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCNG/cng-algorithm-identifiers. Note: only hash algorithms, check OS support
    'Error handling not implemented!
    On Error GoTo VBErrHandler
    Dim errorMessage As String

    Dim hAlg As LongPtr
    Dim algId As String

    'Open crypto provider
    algId = HashingAlgorithm & vbNullChar
    If BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, StrPtr(algId), 0, 0) Then GoTo ErrHandler
    
    'Determine hash object size, allocate memory
    Dim bHashObject() As Byte
    Dim cmd As String
    cmd = "ObjectLength" & vbNullString
    Dim Length As Long
    If BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, StrPtr(cmd), Length, LenB(Length), 0, 0) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler
    ReDim bHashObject(0 To Length - 1)
    
    'Determine digest size, allocate memory
    Dim hashLength As Long
    cmd = "HashDigestLength" & vbNullChar
    If BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, StrPtr(cmd), hashLength, LenB(hashLength), 0, 0) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim bHash() As Byte
    ReDim bHash(0 To hashLength - 1)
    
    'Create hash object
    Dim hHash As LongPtr
    If BCryptCreateHash(hAlg, hHash, bHashObject(0), Length, 0, 0, 0) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler
    
    'Hash data
    If BCryptHashData(hHash, ByVal pData, lenData) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler
    If BCryptFinishHash(hHash, bHash(0), hashLength, 0) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler
    
    'Return result
    NGHash = bHash
ExitHandler:
    'Cleanup
    If hAlg <> 0 Then BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider hAlg, 0
    If hHash <> 0 Then BCryptDestroyHash hHash
    Exit Function
VBErrHandler:
    errorMessage = "VB Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
ErrHandler:
    If errorMessage <> "" Then MsgBox errorMessage
    Resume ExitHandler
End Function

Public Sub NGRandom(pData As LongPtr, lenData As Long, Optional Algorithm As String = "RNG")
    'Erik A, 2019
    'Fills data at pointer with random bytes
    'Error handling not implemented!
    
    Dim hAlg As LongPtr
    Dim algId As String
    
    'Open crypto provider
    algId = Algorithm & vbNullChar
    BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider hAlg, StrPtr(algId), 0, 0
    
    'Fill bytearray with random data
    BCryptGenRandom hAlg, ByVal pData, lenData, 0
    
    'Cleanup
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider hAlg, 0
End Sub

Public Sub NGRandomW(Data() As Byte, Optional Algorithm As String = "RNG")
    If LBound(Data) = -1 Then Exit Sub
    NGRandom VarPtr(Data(LBound(Data))), UBound(Data) - LBound(Data) + 1, Algorithm
End Sub

Public Function NGEncrypt(pData As LongPtr, lenData As Long, inpIV As LongPtr, inpIVLength As Long, inpSecret As LongPtr, inpSecretLength As Long) As Byte()
    'Encrypt pData using AES encryption, inpIV and inpSecret
    'Input: pData -> mempointer to data. lenData: amount of bytes to encrypt. inpIV: mempointer to IV. inpSecret: mempointer to 128-bits secret.
    'Output: Bytearray containing encrypted data
    Dim errorMessage As String
    On Error GoTo VBErrHandler
    
    Dim hAlg As LongPtr
    Dim algId As String

    'Open algorithm provider
    algId = "AES" & vbNullChar
    BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider hAlg, StrPtr(algId), 0, 0

    'Allocate memory to hold the KeyObject
    Dim cmd As String
    Dim keyObjectLength As Long
    cmd = "ObjectLength" & vbNullString
    BCryptGetProperty hAlg, StrPtr(cmd), keyObjectLength, LenB(keyObjectLength), 0, 0
    Dim bKeyObject() As Byte
    ReDim bKeyObject(0 To keyObjectLength - 1)

    'Check block length = 128 bits, copy IV
    Dim ivLength As Long
    Dim bIV() As Byte
    cmd = "BlockLength" & vbNullChar
    BCryptGetProperty hAlg, StrPtr(cmd), ivLength, LenB(ivLength), 0, 0
    If ivLength > inpIVLength Then
        Debug.Print
    End If
    ReDim bIV(0 To ivLength - 1)
    RtlMoveMemory bIV(0), ByVal inpIV, ivLength

    'Set chaining mode
    cmd = "ChainingMode" & vbNullString
    Dim val As String
    val = "ChainingModeCBC" & vbNullString
    BCryptSetProperty hAlg, StrPtr(cmd), ByVal StrPtr(val), LenB(val), 0

    'Create KeyObject using secret
    Dim hKey As LongPtr
    BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey hAlg, hKey, bKeyObject(0), keyObjectLength, ByVal inpSecret, inpSecretLength, 0

    'Calculate output buffer size, allocate output buffer
    Dim cipherTextLength As Long
    BCryptEncrypt hKey, ByVal pData, lenData, ByVal 0, bIV(0), ivLength, ByVal 0, 0, cipherTextLength, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING
    Dim bCipherText() As Byte
    ReDim bCipherText(0 To cipherTextLength - 1)

    'Encrypt the data
    Dim dataLength As Long
    BCryptEncrypt hKey, ByVal pData, lenData, ByVal 0, bIV(0), ivLength, bCipherText(0), cipherTextLength, dataLength, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING
    
    'Output the encrypted data
    NGEncrypt = bCipherText
    
ExitHandler:
    'Destroy the key
    If hKey <> 0 Then BCryptDestroyKey hKey
    If hAlg <> 0 Then BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider hAlg, 0
    Exit Function
VBErrHandler:
    errorMessage = "VB Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
ErrHandler:
    If errorMessage <> "" Then MsgBox errorMessage
    Resume ExitHandler
End Function

Public Function NGEncryptW(pData() As Byte, pIV() As Byte, pSecret() As Byte) As Byte()
    NGEncryptW = NGEncrypt(VarPtr(pData(LBound(pData))), UBound(pData) - LBound(pData) + 1, VarPtr(pIV(LBound(pIV))), UBound(pIV) - LBound(pIV) + 1, VarPtr(pSecret(LBound(pSecret))), UBound(pSecret) - LBound(pSecret) + 1)
End Function


Public Function NGDecrypt(pData As LongPtr, lenData As Long, pIV As LongPtr, lenIV As Long, pSecret As LongPtr, lenSecret As Long) As Byte()
    Dim errorMessage As String
    On Error GoTo VBErrHandler
    Dim hAlg As LongPtr
    Dim algId As String

    'Open algorithm provider
    algId = "AES" & vbNullChar
    If BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, StrPtr(algId), 0, 0) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler

    'Allocate memory to hold the KeyObject
    Dim cmd As String
    Dim keyObjectLength As Long
    cmd = "ObjectLength" & vbNullString
    If BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, StrPtr(cmd), keyObjectLength, LenB(keyObjectLength), 0, 0) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim bKeyObject() As Byte
    ReDim bKeyObject(0 To keyObjectLength - 1)

    'Calculate the block length for the IV, resize the IV
    Dim ivLength As Long
    Dim bIV() As Byte
    cmd = "BlockLength" & vbNullChar
    If BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, StrPtr(cmd), ivLength, LenB(ivLength), 0, 0) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler
    ReDim bIV(0 To ivLength - 1)
    RtlMoveMemory bIV(0), ByVal pIV, ivLength

    'Set chaining mode
    cmd = "ChainingMode" & vbNullString
    Dim val As String
    val = "ChainingModeCBC" & vbNullString
    If BCryptSetProperty(hAlg, StrPtr(cmd), ByVal StrPtr(val), LenB(val), 0) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler

    'Create KeyObject using secret
    Dim hKey As LongPtr
    If BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAlg, hKey, bKeyObject(1), keyObjectLength, ByVal pSecret, lenSecret, 0) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler

    'Calculate output buffer size, allocate output buffer
    Dim OutputSize As Long
    If BCryptDecrypt(hKey, ByVal pData, lenData, ByVal 0, bIV(0), ivLength, ByVal 0, 0, OutputSize, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim bDecrypted() As Byte
    ReDim bDecrypted(0 To OutputSize - 1)

    'Decrypt the data
    Dim dataLength As Long
    If BCryptDecrypt(hKey, ByVal pData, lenData, ByVal 0, bIV(0), ivLength, bDecrypted(0), OutputSize, dataLength, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING) <> 0 Then GoTo ErrHandler

    NGDecrypt = bDecrypted
    
    'Cleanup
ExitHandler:
    BCryptDestroyKey hKey
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider hAlg, 0
    Exit Function
VBErrHandler:
    errorMessage = "VB Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
ErrHandler:
    If errorMessage <> "" Then MsgBox errorMessage
    GoTo ExitHandler
End Function

Public Function NGDecryptW(pData() As Byte, pIV() As Byte, pSecret() As Byte) As Byte()
    NGDecryptW = NGDecrypt(VarPtr(pData(LBound(pData))), UBound(pData) - LBound(pData) + 1, VarPtr(pIV(LBound(pIV))), UBound(pIV) - LBound(pIV) + 1, VarPtr(pSecret(LBound(pSecret))), UBound(pSecret) - LBound(pSecret) + 1)
End Function

Public Function EncryptData(inpData() As Byte, inpKey() As Byte) As Byte()
    'SHA1 the key and data
    Dim keyHash() As Byte
    keyHash = HashBytes(inpKey, "SHA1")
    Dim dataHash() As Byte
    dataHash = HashBytes(inpData, "SHA1")
    Dim dataLength As Long
    dataLength = UBound(inpData) - LBound(inpData) + 1
    Dim toEncrypt() As Byte
    'To encrypt = Long (4 bytes) + dataLength + SHA1 (20 bytes)
    ReDim toEncrypt(0 To dataLength + 23)
    'Append length (in bytes) to start of array
    RtlMoveMemory toEncrypt(0), dataLength, 4
    'Then data
    RtlMoveMemory toEncrypt(4), inpData(LBound(inpData)), dataLength
    'Then hash of data
    RtlMoveMemory toEncrypt(dataLength + 4), dataHash(0), 20
    
    'Generate IV
    Dim IV(0 To 15) As Byte
    NGRandomW IV
    'Encrypt data
    Dim encryptedData() As Byte
    encryptedData = NGEncrypt(VarPtr(toEncrypt(0)), dataLength + 24, VarPtr(IV(0)), 16, VarPtr(keyHash(0)), 16)
    'Deallocate copy made to encrypt
    Erase toEncrypt
    'Extend encryptedData to append IV
    ReDim Preserve encryptedData(LBound(encryptedData) To UBound(encryptedData) + 16)
    'Append IV
    RtlMoveMemory encryptedData(UBound(encryptedData) - 15), IV(0), 16
    'Return result
    EncryptData = encryptedData
End Function

Public Function DecryptData(inpData() As Byte, inpKey() As Byte, outDecrypted() As Byte) As Boolean
    If LBound(inpData) <> 0 Then Exit Function 'Array must start at 0
    Dim arrLength As Long
    arrLength = UBound(inpData) + 1
    'IV = 16 bytes, length = 4 bytes
    If arrLength < 20 Then Exit Function
    'SHA1 the key
    Dim keyHash() As Byte
    keyHash = HashBytes(inpKey, "SHA1")
    'Get the pointer to the IV
    Dim pIV As LongPtr
    pIV = VarPtr(inpData(UBound(inpData) - 15)) 'Last 16 bytes = IV
    'Decrypt the data
    Dim decryptedData() As Byte
    decryptedData = NGDecrypt(VarPtr(inpData(0)), UBound(inpData) - LBound(inpData) - 15, pIV, 16, VarPtr(keyHash(0)), 16)
    'Check we got some data
    If StrPtr(decryptedData) = 0 Then Exit Function ' Weirdly, this checks for uninitialized byte arrays
    If UBound(decryptedData) < 3 Then Exit Function
    'Get the data length
    Dim dataLength As Long
    RtlMoveMemory dataLength, decryptedData(0), 4
    'Check if length is valid, with invalid key length = random data
    If dataLength > (UBound(decryptedData) - 3) Or dataLength < 0 Then Exit Function
    'Hash the decrypted data
    Dim hashResult() As Byte
    hashResult = NGHash(VarPtr(decryptedData(4)), dataLength, "SHA1")
    'Verify the hash
    Dim l As Byte
    For l = 0 To 19
        If hashResult(l) <> decryptedData(l + 4 + dataLength) Then
            'Stored hash not equal to hash with decrypted data, key incorrect or encrypted data tampered with
            'Don't touch output, return false by default
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    'Initialize output array
    ReDim outDecrypted(0 To dataLength - 1)
    'Copy data to output array
    RtlMoveMemory outDecrypted(0), decryptedData(4), dataLength
    DecryptData = True
End Function

Public Function EncryptString(inpString As String, inpKey As String) As String
    Dim Data() As Byte
    Data = inpString
    Dim key() As Byte
    key = inpKey
    EncryptString = ToBase64(EncryptData(Data, key))
End Function

Public Function DecryptString(inpEncryptedString As String, inpKey As String) As String
    Dim Data() As Byte
    Data = Base64ToBytes(inpEncryptedString)
    Dim key() As Byte
    key = inpKey
    Dim out() As Byte
    DecryptData Data, key, out
    DecryptString = out
End Function
```

And an easy check in the immediate window to see it works:

```vb
?EncryptString("Secret data", "Key") 'Returns seemingly random data, changing every call
?DecryptString(EncryptString("Secret data", "Other key"), "Other key")
'Test that long keys and long strings work, returns True since encrypted + decrypted = original
?DecryptString(EncryptString(String(100000, "A"), String(10000, "B")), String(10000, "B")) = String(100000, "A")
```

Comment: Erik, I wish to include most of this module in a project. How can I credit you properly?

Comment: @Gustav A link to this post + my username + date of retrieval in a comment will do, thanks for asking

Comment: @Gustav Be sure to use the recent edit, the previous version assumed the decrypted data was valid and could segfault if it wasn't and the length portion gave a large number

Comment: OK, Erik. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Decrypting will return no output if `Option Compare Text` is in force. See edit, please.

Comment: Erik, it took a while to collect the stuff, but now it is on-line at GitHub: [VBA.Cryptography](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Cryptography). Thanks again for getting me started.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks for sharing a more easy to use example, and including hashing functions. A note: for your password storage and hashing, I strongly recommend performing unicode normalization before hashing, else users might run into inexplicably wrong passwords since café (`"cafe" & chrw(&H0301)`) is not equal to café (`"caf" &  chrw(&H00E9)`). If desired I can share an example of how to perform unicode normalization in VBA.

Comment: Yes, please, that seems highly relevant. I must admit, that I've never touched unicode normalization.

Comment: @Gustav I've shared a self-answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72096448/7296893)

Comment: That was fast! Thank you. I'll study it closer and implement it - can take a little while though, as other tasks are lined up.

Comment: I have browsed the docs of the links of yours and think I understand the rationale behind unicode normalization. But I can't imagine a situation where a user would input the password in another way than originally typed, other than the user somehow is fooled or forced to do so. How could that happen? Would you have an example of such a situation, please?

Comment: @Gustav I've heard it can happen when different keyboard layouts and language settings are in the mix, which I encounter often at my work (university, international students with BYOD). It certainly can happen after migrating the database to something online, where different OSes are in the mix as well (and if you don't normalize immediately, you can't patch it in later). More theoretically, it could also happen after breaking changes are introduced in unicode, for example a new character is added which was previously typed using two characters (which is why you want KD).

Comment: OK, Erik, that makes sense, indeed the BYOD thing. Thank you.