# Why do i get error by reading "ü" and "ä" in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, character-encoding, syntax-error

I wrote a code for a Project Search in a Table. I am comparing the input from a Project Number with the Project Numbers in the table and when the number is found i want to save the name of the Project in a Variable. It works perfectly, but in 2 projects the characters "ä" and "ö" are not readed as a whole but separate... see the picture.

[image]

I doin´t have any idea why and what to do to avoid this problem.

This problem is just with this project. All other projects with this character are working well. Any comments or help will be apreciated.

Comment: It's about [Unicode normalization forms](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/): you see e.g. `a` (U+0061,  *Latin Small Letter A*) followed by `̈` (U+0308,  *Combining Diaeresis*) instead of `ä` (U+00E4,  *Latin Small Letter A With Diaeresis*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform unicode normalization for password storage in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096448/how-do-i-perform-unicode-normalization-for-password-storage-in-vba)